# Access SQL - Left join, Group by, Count(select where)

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, left-join

I have 2 tables.

tbl1 has colums:

```
id1, someothercolumns
```

tbl2 has colums:

```
id2, id1, bool
```

I can join them by id1 without problem. I can do this:

```
SELECT tbl1.id1, Count(tbl2.id2) AS CountOfid2
FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.id1= tbl2.id1
GROUP BY tbl1.id1;
```

But I don't want to count all items from tbl2, on those where

```
bool=false
```

So, I want to see all records from tbl1 and not count all records from tbl2. I tried with sub-select, but Access doesn't like my ideas. :(
Can you help me?

Comment: No @yosidahari, I can't. Read it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

```
SELECT tbl1.id1, Count(tmptbl.id2) AS CountOfid2
FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT tbl2.id1, tbl2.id2 FROM tbl2 WHERE bool=false) as tmptbl ON tbl1.id1= tmptbl.id1
GROUP BY tbl1.id1;
```

Give me cookie!

Answer (score 0):

please test this script:

```
   select distinct t1.id1,t4.countofID2 from tbl1 t1
   left outer join 
   (select t3.con as countofID2 ,* from tbl2
   ,(SELECT COUNT(t2.id2)as con 

   FROM tbl2 t2) as t3)as t4
   on(t1.id1=t4.id1)
```

Be happy .....